# How do I create all permutations with three lists? Python

Tags: python

Lets say I have three lists.

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
c=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I want to create all permutations with a,b, and c.

```
from itertools import permutations
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
c=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

perm = permutations([a,b,c])
for i in list(perm): 
   print (i)
```

This gives

```
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

which is not what I'm looking for.

I'm looking for a solution

```
[1,1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,1],[1,4,1].....
```

Is this possible

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for product:

```
from itertools import product
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

perm = product(a, repeat=3)
for i in list(perm): 
   print (i)
```

If a, b, c not the same list use:  `product(a, b, c)`